# What is the plus symbol (+) in generics?

Tags: generics, rust

I am on [chapter 19 of *The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-00-advanced-features.html) when I saw this code

```
Box<dyn Fn() + Send + 'static>
```

What does it do and why is there the plus sign (`+`) in there? I don't remember encountering this in a previous chapter.

How is `Box::new(|| println!("hi"))` a `Box<dyn Fn() + Send + 'static>`?

Comment: take a look at the [rust by example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/generics/bounds.html)
you also should reread the chapiter 10 of the rust-lang book, the `+` operator is used to combie bounds from cargo doc: ```When working with generics, the type parameters often must use traits as bounds to stipulate what functionality a type implements. For example, the following example uses the trait Display to print and so it requires T to be bound by Display; that is, T must implement Display.``` in your case the `Box` contains a dynamic object that implement `Send` with `'static` lifetime

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @Asya Corbeau pointed me back to chapter 10, it is the [Specifying Multiple Trait Bounds with the + Syntax](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-02-traits.html#specifying-multiple-trait-bounds-with-the--syntax)